# Visual Studio Community 2013 too slow

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, lag

when i open a project (even if it's empty) in VS Community 2013, it gets laggy. I searched solutions on Google but none of them worked.
I tried to put source to none. I tried to disable Automatically adjust visual experience based on cleint perfomance, and a lot more solutions but nothing worked.
My pc spefications are:
Intel Core i5-3340
Nvidia GeForce GT610
Ram 4gb
500GB HDD
I had the same problem in the same computer with VS Ultimate.
Other thing that i found is that if i open the "Options" window in VS the CPU use is on 0.1%, but if i close the Options window the consumption goes to 27% and the program almost ever stops responding.
Sorry for bad english.
(With slow i mean low fps)

Comment: Welcome to the world of big IDE's. Are your running many other processes simultaneously?

Comment: The memory size and HDD speed matters a lot.

Comment: There can be multiple issues regarding IDE performance, and for Visual Studio there are tons of articles, such as https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2894215. Simply switching to another big IDE like Eclipse won't ultimately solve the issue, as Eclipse is also well known for its slowness and high memory usage.

Comment: You might have a look at [Visual Studio 2015 extremely slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395686/visual-studio-2015-extremely-slow/34450140#34450140).